# How to get the values in array

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to return the values in the array vars but I am only getting this back. I am quite new so please can someone explain what these values are ad why they aren't returning 1 or 0 for the state of the checkbutton?

```
[<tkinter.IntVar object at 0x0318BCD0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x0318BD70>, <tkinter.IntVar 
object at 0x0318BDD0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x0318BE30>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x0318BE90>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x0318BF10>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x0318BF70>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x0318BFD0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196050>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196070>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x031960D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196110>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196150>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196190>, <tkinter.IntVar object 
at 0x031961D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196210>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196250>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196290>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x031962D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196310>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196350>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196390>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x031963D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196410>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196450>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196490>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x031964D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196510>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196550>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196590>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x031965D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196610>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196650>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196690>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x031966D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196710>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196750>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196790>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x031967D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196810>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196850>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196890>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x031968D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196910>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196950>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196990>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x031969D0>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196A10>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196A50>, <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03196A90>]
```

This is the code that I am using from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770537/listbox-with-checkbuttons-in-python-with-tkinter) post

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

checklist = tk.Text(root, width=20)
checklist.pack()

vars = []
for i in range(50):
    var = tk.IntVar()
    vars.append(var)
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(checklist, text=i, variable=var)
    checklist.window_create("end", window=checkbutton)
    checklist.insert("end", "\n")

checklist.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=checklist.yview)

# disable the widget so users can't insert text into it
checklist.configure(state="disabled")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no code on getting those values.

Comment: @acw1668 ah sorry I basically did a print(vars) but the question is all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value out of a `tk.IntVar()` you need to use the `.get()` method. So if you want to get a list of values you need to use `.get()` on every element of the `vars` array.

And `vars` is a saved keyword so you should use it, you could use the name tk_vars instead.

```
values = []

for var in tk_vars:
   values.append(var.get())

print(values)
```

And if you want to use a list comprehension:

`values = [var.get() for var in tk_vars]`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the `.get()` method on `var`. Read more about these methods [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-setting-and-retrieving-values-of-tkinter-variable/).